# Segmentation fault with PCL when transforming point clouds

Tags: ros2, pcl, ros-humble

I am getting a segmentation fault with pcl::transformPointCloud.

This is all I am getting on the terminal:

```
ros2 run cpp_tests icp_test
initialized
101201
Transforming
[ros2run]: Segmentation fault
```

My PCL version is 1.12.1.

The line that is causing the error is:

```
pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_in, *cloud_icp, icp_transform);
```

cloud_in and cloud_icp are both `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr`, and icp_transform is obtained from PCL and is `Eigen::Matrix4f`. cloud_in had the input cloud in it, cloud_icp would be empty (it was defined as `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_icp;` but not used before this point).

I would like to solve this issue or find a workaround. As far as I can tell, I have only PCL 1.12.1 on my system. I am using ROS2 humble on Ubuntu 22.04. This was compiled using `colcon build --symlink-install` and compiled without any errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the definition of `cloud_icp` from your first post, you just declare a pointer of type`¹`

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>
```

However, its not pointing to an existing `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` Pointcloud and thus your program crashes when entering the function.
The approach from your own answer

```
cloud_icp = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(360,1));
```

creates an underlying Pointcloud.

`¹`: More precisely, it is a smart pointer of type [`std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>`](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.
Adding

```
cloud_icp = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(360,1));
```

to the constructor solved the problem.
I don't know why that helped.

Comment: With the definition of `cloud_icp` from your first post, you just declare a pointer of type `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` (but its not pointing to an existing `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` Pointcloud and thus your program crashes when entering the function). The approach in your own answer creates an underlying Pointcloud.

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to add that as an answer?

Comment: I advise you to read up on c++ a bit; I found [Learn C++](https://www.learncpp.com/) a very good resource.